# Where are the hexagon grid details in the book?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I can't remember if it was the CRB or the GMG but I remember reading about using the hexagon grid for exploration and it talked about the area of the hexes and such but I can't find it again in the book.

Anyone know?

Comment: It's generally a good idea not to accept answers too quickly, but to accept answers after about a day so that you don't discourage other users that might have something to add from answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's in "Ultimate Campaign" CRB, "Exploration" section